# Changing the DNS server IP address(es) on O2 Router

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp-server

A simple Google search has revealed [a process whereby this can be done](http://www.o2help.co.uk/router-change-dns/) (weirdly, it isn't something that can be done via the HTTP GUI), but there is a strange command in the instructions:

> 3) Paste in the following lines
>   changing primdns and secdns to
>   whatever DNS servers you wish to use
>   (use the little icon at the top-left
>   of the command prompt window in order
>   to paste). You do not need to edit the
>   line starting with "dns client
>   dnsadd". The example below sets your
>   DNS to the Google Public DNS service.
>   Use "none" for secdns if you don't
>   have a secondary DNS server.
>
> ```
> dns server config state=disabled
> dhcp server config state=disabled
> dhcp server lease flush
> dhcp server pool config name=LAN_private primdns=8.8.8.8 secdns=8.8.4.4
> dhcp server config state=enabled
> dns client flush
> dns client dnsadd addr=87.194.255.155  <-- What is this for?
> saveall
> exit
> ```

I have indicated the line above, and cannot figure out for the life of me what this is for?

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the DNS server that the _router itself_ will be using. (`dhcp server ...` commands only change the DNS servers to be offered to connected computers.)

Comment: @grawity: that was my thought too... but I see no reason this would need to change or how it's connected - yet it apparently is. When they talk about changing back to O2's default settings, they set it back to 127.0.0.1. Seems odd to use itself as it's own DNS server in some circumstances and not others.